# Covariance between dependent Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, covariance, poisson-process

> Let $N_t$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ and let $T_i$ be the arrival of the $i^{th}$ event. Let $Y_i$ be
>   i.i.d. with distribution $P(Y_i=1) = p$, $P(Y_i = 0) = 1-p$. Define
>   the processes: $$Z_t := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i 1_{T_i \leq t}$$ $$V_t
> := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-Y_i) 1_{T_i \leq t}$$
>
> Compute $E[Z_tV_t]$.

My Attempt:

We could write 
$$Z_t = \sum_{i=1}^{X_t} Y_i $$ $$V_t
= \sum_{i=1}^{W_t} (1-Y_i) $$
where 
$X_t = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1_{\tau_i \leq t}$ and $W_t = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1_{\tilde{\tau_i} \leq t}$.

I showed that $Z_t$ and $V_t$ are both Poisson process with parameters $\lambda p$, and $\lambda (1-p)$. This was determined simply by observing the MGF of these these processes.

Then, 
$E[X_tZ_t]= E[\sum_{i=1}^{X_t} Y_i \sum_{j=1}^{W_t} (1-Y_j)] = E[E[\sum_{i=1}^{X_t} Y_i \sum_{j=1}^{W_t} (1-Y_j)|X_t, W_t]]$.

Now the inner expectation is a function of $W_t$ and $X_t$.

$E[\sum_{i=1}^{X_t} Y_i \sum_{j=1}^{W_t} (1-Y_j)|X_t, W_t] = E[\sum_{i=1}^{X_t}\sum_{j=1}^{W_t}Y_i  (1-Y_j)|X_t, W_t]$

but I am stuck evaluating it.

Comment: $V_t+Z_t=N_t$, hence $var(V_t)+var(Z_t)+2cov(V_t,Z_t)=var(N_t)$. Note that $V_t$ and $Z_t$ are Poisson processes themselves, hence $2cov(V_t,Z_t)=t-pt-(1-p)t=0$ and it follows that $E(Z_tV_t)=p(1-p)t^2$.

Comment: @A.S. Should have realized this. But, aren't you missing $\lambda's$ everywhere? For example, $Var(N_t) = \lambda t$.